# Sphere curvature as calculated from Liouville's equation

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

Liouville's equation for Gauss curvature tells us, that when Riemannian metric has the form $f^2(du^2+dv^2)$, then its Gauss curvature $K$ is expressed by the following equation:
$$-Kf^2=\Delta_{0}log(f)$$
where $\Delta_{0}=\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial u^2}+\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial v^2}$.

Consider a sphere with metric (due to stereographic projection):
$$\frac{du^2+dv^2}{(1+u^2+v^2)^2}$$
Therefore we can apply Liouville's equation to find the curvature of the sphere with $f=\frac{1}{1+u^2+v^2}$.However, calculating the curvature of the sphere in this way I get $K=4$, which is not true. And I cann't spot my mistake. 
Here are some calculations:
$$log(f)=-log(1+u^2+v^2)$$
$$\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial u^2}log(f)=-\frac{2(1-u^2+v^2)}{(1+u^2+v^2)^2}$$
$$\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial u^2}log(f)=-\frac{2(1+u^2-v^2)}{(1+u^2+v^2)^2}$$
$$\Delta_{0}log(f)=-\frac{2(1-u^2+v^2)}{(1+u^2+v^2)^2}-\frac{2(1+u^2-v^2)}{(1+u^2+v^2)^2}=\frac{-4}{(1+u^2+v^2)^2}$$
Therefore:
$$-K\frac{1}{(1+u^2+v^2)^2}=\frac{-4}{(1+u^2+v^2)^2}$$
Hence Gauss curvature of the sphere is (not):
$$K=4$$
My question: where is that mistake?

Comment: In case it's helpful, your metric arises by stereographic projection from $N = (0, 0, 1)$ onto the $(x, y)$-plane of the sphere of radius $1/2$ centered at $(0, 0, 1/2)$. To some people, this is conventional, and in any case the curvature of this sphere is indeed $4$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your formula

$$\frac{du^2+dv^2}{(1+u^2+v^2)^2}$$

is incorect. It should be

$$\frac{4(du^2+dv^2)}{(1+u^2+v^2)^2}$$

Comment: Yes indeed. Probably it is the most difficult task to spot a typo in my own calculations. Thanks!